# Reusing types with message contracts

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF service and a client and I want both to share the same class library so they both have access to the same types. My issue is that one of the classes is a `MessageContract` because it is an object that is used to upload files to the server via streaming. The class is as follows:

```
[MessageContract]
public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
{

    private string fileName;
    private long length;
    private System.IO.Stream fileByteStream;

    public string FileName
    {
        set { this.fileName = value; }
        get { return this.fileName; }
    }

    public long Length
    {
        set { this.length = value; }
        get { return this.length; }
    }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream
    {
        set { this.fileByteStream = value; }
        get { return this.fileByteStream; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (fileByteStream != null)
        {
            fileByteStream.Dispose();
            fileByteStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This class is contained in a library that is shared between the server and the client. If I comment out the line that says `[MessageContract]` and then update the service reference, I am able to successfully share the type with the client and the service reference does not try to re-implement the type on its own. However, in order for streaming to work I need to make sure that this class is indeed a `MessageContract` so that the WCF service knows to only expect a single body member in the message and to deal with it appropriately.

If I uncomment the line that says `[MessageContract]` and update the service reference on the client side, it tries to re-implement `RemoteFileInfo` via the service reference instead of reusing the `RemoteFileInfo` that already exists in the library that both the service and the client are sharing. This means I end up with two of the same classes, `MyClientProject.Shared.RemoteFileInfo` and `ServiceReference.RemoteFileInfo`, which is ambiguous and causes the code to throw tons of errors.

I can get around it (sloppily) by commenting out the `[MessageContract]` line, updating the service reference, and then uncommenting the line on the service side before starting the service, so the client side thinks that it is just a normal class but the WCF service thinks its a `MessageContract`. This seems very silly to have to do and I am convinced theres a better way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already sharing all your data contracts, what's the point of not sharing your service contract interface as well, and simply avoid doing code generation at all? That would make far more sense.

Comment: Thats one approach, yes. But for this project I am just trying to figure out how I can basically have 2 different types of the same class, where one is a messagecontract and one is not.

Comment: If I shared my service contracts, how would that allow both client and server to use the same RemoteFileInfo? Woulnd't the service still try to re-implement it?